# Is it not possible to create an Amazon Lightsail instance in a private VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to create an Amazon Lightsail instance in my private VPC. From the console we do not have an option of choosing the VPC. Anyone know if it is not possible. I don't find an answer on the internet.

Comment: What's the purpose of running a Lightsail inside a private VPC? Why not use an EC2 instead?

Comment: @jellycsc , basically for cost cutting and at this point for our requirement light sale is good. Do you know if we cannot do this ?

Comment: I think you can peer to an Amazon VPC, but not directly create the Amazon Lightsail instance in your own VPC.